# Cannot locate item in list after serialization

Tags: java, file, arraylist, serialization

First I create item A. Then I add Item A to List A. Then I serialize Item A to a file and then I read Item A from the same file. Finally, I to locate the read item B from List A. Locating the item B in List A fails. The result of the println statement is -1. My question is why?

```
public class ListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Item a = new Item("a");
        List<Item> listA = new ArrayList<Item>();
        listA.add(a);

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("text.dat"));
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {         
            oos.writeObject(a);         

            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("text.dat"));
                    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
                        Item b = (Item) ois.readObject();           
                        System.out.println(listA.indexOf(b));           
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();                    
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

** EDIT 1 **

Where is the code for the item.

```
public class Item implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String mName;

    public Item(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `Item` implement `Serializable`?

Comment: Yes, it does. I added the code to edit 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code :

1. To check if an element is present in a list you need to use `.contains()` Change this

   ```
   listA.indexOf(b);
   ```

   to

   ```
   listA.contains(b);
   ```

   From the [docs,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

   > `boolean contains(Object o)`
   >
   > Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More
   >   formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one
   >   element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).
2. Now, since you are checking the equality of objects your need to
   override
       the `equals()` and `hashcode()` in the `Item` class. Add the following methods to `Item`

   ```
   class Item implements Serializable {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       private String mName;

       // getters and setters

       @Override
       public int hashCode() {
           final int prime = 31;
           int result = 1;
           result = prime * result + ((mName == null) ? 0 : mName.hashCode());
           return result;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object obj) {
           if (this == obj)
               return true;
           if (obj == null)
               return false;
           if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
               return false;
           Item other = (Item) obj;
           if (mName == null) {
               if (other.mName != null)
                   return false;
           } else if (!mName.equals(other.mName))
               return false;
           return true;
       }

   }
   ```

   Now you know that two objects are equal if all properties of the object are of the same value. If you now check the `contains()` it will return `true`.